# how to fix "no network security specified, using platform default" in android studio?

Tags: php, android

I am trying to make a database via 000webhost.com. I keep getting this message showing in the event log whenever I run the app from android studio and it does not insert any record into the database when I click the register button. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

My Register.php contains the following code:-

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("mysql10.000webhost.com", "id385292_dbusername", "contre@777", "id385292_dbname");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

My RegisterActivity.java contains:-

```
package com.example.admin.loginregister;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        final EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        final EditText etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name = etName.getText().toString();
                final String username = etUserName.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Registration Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                    RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, responseListener);
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                    queue.add(registerRequest);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

My RegisterRequest.java contains:-

```
package com.example.admin.loginregister;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.android.volley.Response;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL="https://myandroid47.000webhostapp.com/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name,String username,int age,String password,Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST,REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name",name);
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("password",password);
        params.put("age",age + ""); //We need to add string to convert age i.e int to String.
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are testing on Android 7.0+, I would expect that this message refers to [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html), and I would expect that this message is merely information, not an error.

Comment: Adding the exact error from the log would clarify @CommonsWare 's comment.

Comment: Just a suggestion.  You don't have to disclose your hostname, username and password in the question.